# LoJack protection and recovery for Unix/GNU/Linux running systems?

Tags: security, privacy

The [LoJack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoJack) theft protection and recovery system looks very impressive, especially that they will find and return your computer for you, but the software is for Windows and OS X only.

Is there an equivalent service (including device retrieval service) for computers running GNU/Linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Theft & Loss Protection for Laptops, Notebooks, PDAs with Linux (tuxmobil.org)](http://tuxmobil.org/stolen_laptops.html) offers a pretty large variety of methods for theft prevention, also linking to [a review of a free software/tracking solutions (from 2009).](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9140813/Review_Track_your_stolen_laptop_for_free_with_Prey)

I have tried none of this.

A neat trick mentioned on the linked tuxmobil.org site:

> **The CD/DVD Trick**
>
> Using your laptop in a public library you may rely on their theft protection mechanisms. Just put one of their CDs or DVDs with these litte magnetic tags into the drive. Mounting the media will prevent it from removal. Now imagine the thief leaving the library security gate! Nasty, isn't it? Note: make sure *you* remove the media before passing the gate.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am wondering, though, if there is a service available for Linux machines that will also retrieve and return your computer??

Comment: From the linked review (p. 3), refering to "Prey": *"Its developers **can't do the job of contacting the relevant authorities for you**. Some paid services like LoJack for Laptops, on the other hand, have a support staff on call to do their best to get your notebook back with the authorities' help. That personal attention is what you're buying when you subscribe to certain paid tracking services."*